# Assign indexes of array to boolean value inside an object - optimal way

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find the best way to assign array indices to an object with boolean value. currently my solution is:

```
let l = [{t:1, te: "aa"}, {t:2, te: "aa"},{t:2, te: "aa"} ];
let a = {}
l.map((obj, index) => (a[index] = false));
console.log(a)
```

So if I have an array with 200 objects it will be `{0: false, 1:false, ....}`

I was looking at `Array.reduce()` however, I cannot find a way to do it with that and I always get:

```
var object = Object.assign(...l.map(k => ({ [k]: true })));

{ 
   [object Object]: false
}
```

Is there anyway to do this in one line?

Comment: `l.map(k => ({ [k]: true }))` is not the same as `l.map((obj, index) => (a[index] = false))` - `k` is an object hence the result is `"[object Object]": false`

Comment: Just don't but a new line after the semi-colon. Then it's one line. `/sarcasm`. Stop worrying about how many lines there are in the code and worry more about how readable and maintainable the code is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the objects to an array of entries of `[index, false]`, and turn it into an object:

```js
const l = [{t:1, te: "aa"}, {t:2, te: "aa"},{t:2, te: "aa"} ];
const a = Object.fromEntries(l.map((_, i) => [i, false]));
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index parameter in the `map` callback.

```js
let l = [{t:1, te: "aa"}, {t:2, te: "aa"},{t:2, te: "aa"} ];
var object = Object.assign(...l.map((x, i) => ({
  [i]: true
})));
console.log(object)
```

You can use `Array#reduce` in a similar manner.

```js
let l = [{t:1, te: "aa"}, {t:2, te: "aa"},{t:2, te: "aa"} ];
var object = l.reduce((acc, curr, index) => Object.assign(acc, {
  [index]: true
}), {});
console.log(object)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const l = [{t:1, te: "aa"}, {t:2, te: "aa"},{t:2, te: "aa"} ];
const a = l.reduce((acc, obj, index) =>  { return {...acc, [index] : false }}, {})
console.log(a)
```